# Using Are vs Is with Plethora

Tags: grammar

I have this part of a sentence for a college essay I am writing:

Penn's plethora of student-run groups are a well-suited outlet to continue my extracurriculars.

Do I use are or is after groups? When speaking it, it sounds like "are" is correct. However, grammarly suggests otherwise. I understand that plethora is non-plural, but does the student-run groups after change the subject?

Sorry, I am pretty bad with this grammar stuff, anything helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary perusal reveals **plethora** is an uncountable or singular noun: a noun that has no plural.

Thus:

> Penn's plethora of student-run groups is a well-suited outlet to
>   continue my extracurriculars.

is correct.  **Plethora** is the noun. Prepositional is "of student run groups".